# What does this tattoo character mean?

Tags: meaning

Tattoo symbol, what does it mean?
[image]

Comment: can you give me more information with Tattoo symbol?

Answer (score 2):

The character is [安](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/222/) (safe; secure; content).  By itself, it is innocent enough.

However, "安" is also the last character in the name of a notorious Hong Kong Triad gang "[新義安](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E5%90%88%E6%9C%83)"

In short, this  tattoo reminds me of this particular crime syndicate, consider it is on a bicep-- a body part that represents power and strength...

If the owner of this tattoo is a Hong Kong Chinese, I would stay clear of him, just in case.